# How to calculate an imaginary number to high exponent?

Tags: complex-numbers

How can I calculate something like $(i+1)^{33}$ or similar high exponent without the use of a calculator?

Comment: Write it as an exponential.

Comment: Have you had DeMoivre's Theorem?  You would re-write $i + 1 $ in "polar form" and apply that Theorem.  That's pretty much what the quick way is.

Answer (score 5):

**HINT**

Euler's formula $$e^{i \theta} = \cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta)$$ and recall that any complex number can be written as $x+iy = r e^{i \theta}$.

Move your mouse over the gray area for the answer.

> We have $1+i = \sqrt2 e^{i\pi/4}$. Hence, $$(1+i)^{33} = (\sqrt2 e^{i \pi/4})^{33} = 2^{33/2} e^{i(33 \pi/4)} = 2^{33/2} e^{i \pi/4} = 2^{16}(1+i)$$

Comment: Not math, but about posting answers -- I'm not finding it easily on a meta search: how do you make a grey "spoiler box"?

Comment: @RecklessReckoner You need to have `>!` and then write the text.

Comment: Just the one time, or is there a terminating delimiter?  And thanks!

Comment: The `Enter` key is needed to start and is also used as a delimited. I added an example [here to clarify.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-answers/4669#4669)

Comment: Thank you again for your assistance!